# "Патетическая ипохондрия" - можно ли так сказать?

Tags: стилистика

Можно ли сказать: "Патетическая ипохондрия"?

Comment: А что сказать хочется? Смысл каков?

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу причин запрещать.
"Патетика" и "ипохондрия" - совсем не антонимы. Первое означает чувственное воспроизведение (обычно - звуковое), второе - внутреннее состояние.
Первое совсем не обязательно связано с каким-то душевным подъемом исполнителя, второе не подразумевает, но и не исключает некоторого пафоса.
То есть это сочетание совсем не оксюморон, а что-то наподобие "соленого арбуза" - не совсем понятно, но вполне возможно.

Конечно, такое сочетание несколько необычно, поэтому надо видеть контекст, хотя бы для того, чтобы убедится в правильности понимания значения этих слов автором.

Гадать, что это может означать у автора, не хочется, лучше его переспросить.

Answer (score 1):

Отчего же нет, скажите. Получится замечательный в своей свежести каламбур:

ПРИПОДНЯТАЯ ПОДАВЛЕННОСТЬ.

Или:

СТРАСТНАЯ УГНЕТЁННОСТЬ.

Comment: Автор не говорил о намерении шутить.

Comment: Автор спросил: можно? Отвечаю: запросто. И указую, как означенное явление будет называться.

Comment: "Если очень хочется, то можно" ©

Answer (score 0):

**Патетическая ипохондрия** – возможно,  это термин из области политики.

Вообще говоря, **ипохондрия связана с мнительностью**, с постоянным ощущением болезненных явлений в организме, **но при этом  бывают разные виды ипохондрии:** (1) навязчивая тревожность, угнетенность и (2) активный поиск способов выздоровления и поддержания идеального здоровья. Вот во  втором случае ипохондрию как раз можно связать с патетикой, то есть с пафосом и страстной взволнованностью.

Тогда патетическая ипохондрия  в политике – **это  пафосное обличение негативных явлений   общественной жизни и страстный поиск излечения от них**.

[Ипохондрия | dolgojit.net](http://dolgojit.net/ipokhondriia.php)